# How to calculate time complexity of recursions with memoization?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, big-o, complexity-theory, memoization

What is time complexity of the code below? I know it has recursive call multiple times so it should probably be 3^n, but still each time it initializes array of length n, which is latter used and it kinda confuses me. What should be time complexity if we would add additional array to apply memoization? This below is solution for Hackerrank Java 1D Array (Hard) task.

```
public static boolean solve(int n, int m, int[] arr, boolean[] visited, int           curr) {
    if (curr + m >= n || curr + 1 == n) {
        return true;
    }

    boolean[] newVisited = new boolean[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        newVisited[i] = visited[i];
    }

    boolean s = false;
    if (!visited[curr+1] && arr[curr+1] == 0) {
        newVisited[curr+1] = true;
        s = solve(n,m,arr,newVisited,curr+1);
    }
    if (s) {
        return true;
    }
    if (m > 1 && arr[curr+m] == 0 && !visited[curr+m]) {
        newVisited[curr+m] = true;
        s = solve(n,m,arr,newVisited,curr+m);
    }
    if (s) {
        return true;
    }
    if (curr > 0 && arr[curr-1] == 0 && !visited[curr-1]) {
        newVisited[curr-1] = true;
        s = solve(n,m,arr,newVisited,curr-1); 
    }
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation does indeed seem to have exponential complexity. I did not really think about this part of your question. It is perhaps a bit tedious to come up with a worst case scenario. But one "at-least-pretty-bad" scenario would be to have the first `n-m` elements in `arr` set to 0 and the last `m` elements set to 1. A lot of branching right there, not really making use of the memoization mechanism. I would guess that your solution it is at least exponential in `n/m`.

Here is another solution. We can rephrase the problem as a graph one. Let the elements in your array be the vertices of a *directed* graph and let there be an edge in between every pair of vertices of one of the following forms: `(x,x-1)`, `(x,x+1)` and `(x,x+m)`, if both ends of such an edge have value 0. Add an additional vertex `t` to your graph. Also add an edge from every vertex with value 0 in `{n-m+1,n-m+2,...,n}` to `t`. So we have no more than `3n+m` edges in our graph. Now, your problem is equivalent to determining if there is a path from vertex `0` to `t` in the graph we have just constructed. This can be achieved by running a Depth First Search starting from vertex `0`, having complexity `O(|E|)`, which in our case is `O(n+m)`.

Coming back to your solution, you are doing pretty much the same thing (perhaps without realizing it). The only real difference is that you are copying the `visited` array into `newVisited` and thus never really using all that memoization :p So, just eliminate `newVisited`, use `visited` wherever you are using `newVisited` and check what happens.